# Django apache2 url direct with no base url

Tags: django, apache, subdomain, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

I have installed on Djagno project on Apache and it was working very well.
But after I set the base url of the projects, it breaks things.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomainname.com
    Alias /static /path/to/project/static
    <Directory /path/to/project/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /path/to/project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess projectname python-path=/var/bin/python3 python-home=/path/to/project
    WSGIProcessGroup projectname
    WSGIScriptAlias /base_url  /path/to/project/wsgi.py
    #Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog /path/to/project/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    CustomLog /path/to/project/access.log combined
    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

it's working fine.
The problem is that.

```
<a href="/all">All</a>
```

When I click the link `All` is should direct to `/base_url/all`, but it goes to `/all`, so I had to manually type `/base_url`.
How can I fix this problem. Should I change the all urls in html pages with `base_url`?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be hard-coding URLs in templates at all. Use the `{% url %}` tag, which among things will take the URL prefix into account.